# How long bluetoothLeScanner scan time?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I changed code

```
BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan
```

to

```
 BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(callback)
```

So, Scanning performance up enough my think, but I don't know bluetoothLeScanner scan time.

`BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan`
 has changing scan time.

please, answer.

Comment: I want scanning forever until connected if ble-card disconnected. if scanning time is over, restart scanning ble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to stop Scan using handler .Use this code to stop scan After 10 second

```
BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(callback);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 BluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(callback);

            }
        }, 10000);
```

Comment: So if i don't use stop scan code, is scanning run for hours?

Comment: Accept it as Answer.Thanks

Comment: Does not scan forever. Stops scanning after something like 7-10 minutes.

Comment: @DanielF, do you have a source for this 7-10 minutes limit? I just did a quick test, I called startScan(callback) in a foreground service, locked the screen, and 15 minutes later I enabled a couple of beacons and they were detected by the scanner.

Comment: @DoruChidean no source, that was my experience. But I also solved the issue back then (I can't remember how, I would have to go through the code).

Comment: From Android 7 new limitations has been introduced. A scan cycle can not exceed 30 minutes, after which the scan is automatically stopped and the mode changes to "opportunistic". This mode means that you get a scan result only if other apps are running bluetooth scans